# title tag is not working: displaying as paragraph text on live website

Tags: html

This is the first time this has happened to me, and I have been programming websites for about a year now. My text that is in my title tag is literally showing up on my website live.. (I can click on it and highlight it, etc...)

Here is my markup:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"
<title>Smokey's Ski and Snowboarding :: Ski and Snowboarding Shop :: Whistler Vancouver</title>
<meta name="description" content="The ski bums of Canada's great Whistler region.">
<link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

</body>
</html>
```

I seriously see nothing wrong with my markup, should I just make a new document?

Comment: *I have been programming websites for about a year* but you haven't built skills to debug, it was just 10 lines merely..

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a closing bracket on `<meta charset="UTF-8"` so it should be

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

OR

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code on my machine and it working fine. It is displaying the correct Title.

In my opinion, it could be some "Browser Cache problem" (Use Control + F5) or may be some  you had written and you haven't noticed (because in notepad we can scroll horizontally infinite where we might have BY MISTAKE wrote and forgot as we usually see merely 8 inch screen) .
I would suggest you to start from a new Document and ignore this thing as it is completely illogical and is nothing to be worried about. Concentrate on your main project and watch out for small mistakes.
Hope this will help you !